# Solution to implement category in Java

Tags: java

> You want to create a program for the management of a telephone book.
> For each person are provided for the following personal information:
>
> ```
> Surname
> Name
> Title
> E-mail address (can not contain spaces and must contain the @ symbol)
> Company
> Position
> ```
>
> For every person you can store the following telephone numbers (one for each category)
>
> ```
> Home
> Office
> Mobile Phone.
> ```
>
> You can also store a list of other phone numbers. For each of the other numbers, you must store over to the phone number
> a description of the number.

Here it is a homework I have to make for this evening in Java.
My issue is how I can implement the various category: Home,Office,ecc...Which is the best solution to implement those category? maybe an enum?

Here it is my implementation:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Persona {

private String Name;
private String surname;
private String title;
private String mail_addr;
private String company
private String position;
private Phone homePhone;
private Phone officePhone;
private Phone mobilePhone;
private Collection<Phone> otherphonesList

public Persona(String n,String s,String t,String m,String c,String p,Phone hp,Phone of,Phone mp,Collection<Phone> otherphones)
{
    name=n;
    surname=s;
    title=t;
    mail_addr=m;
    company=c;
    position=p;
    homePhone=hp;
    officePhone=of;
    mobilePhone=mp;
    otherphonesList=new ArrayList<Phone>(otherphones);
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public String getSurname()
{
    return surname;
}

public String getTitle()
{
    return title;
}

public String getMail()
{
    return mail_addr;
}

public String getCompany()
{
    return company;
}

public String getPosition()
{
    return position;
}
}


public class Phone {

private String  phone;
private String description;

public Phone(String phone,String description)
{
    this.phone=phone;
    this.description=description;
}

public String getPhone()
{
    return phone;
}

public String getDescription()
{
    return description;
}


}
```

Comment: and don't forget the `title` field :)

Comment: And, please, follow [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html). s/Name/name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a PhoneBook class with fields you need:

```
public class PhoneBook {
    private Phone homePhone;
    private Phone officePhone;
    private Phone mobilePhone;
    private List<Phone> otherPhones;
    ..getters/setters..
}

public class Phone {
    private String phone;
    private String description;
    ..getters/setters..
}
```

Comment: I tought to this solution...create a type phone

Comment: And use an `enum` for the categories. Note: For homework-type questions, it's usually better to give suggestions instead of complete solutions.

Comment: why use enum if I have already created the attributes homePhone,officePhone...?

Comment: @Mazzy you don't use separate attributes for homePhone, ... but a `List<Phone>` to store the numbers and an `enum` type in the `Phone` class to define the type of the instance (home, office,...)

Comment: @Matten the exercise ask me to create the list only for other numbers.the numbers of home,office,eccc must be simple attributes

Comment: @Mazzy the question above does not state to implement the numbers as simple attributes, there is room for interpretations on how to solve this one :)

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at the [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) class to store the phone numbers and add accessors for home, office and mobile phone entries.

Comment: -1 for suggesting a deprecated class. Since Java 1.2, `Map` should be used.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla - of course you're right. I edited my post. As a C# developer Dictionary was the first class which came up in my mind :) Should have read the linked page more carefully, especially the bold part at the top...

Comment: And I can't undo the downvote because SO insists that the answer hasn't been edited since I downvoted it :-((( damn:-(

Comment: @Aaron Digulla now it should work. Thanks for hinting me to the Map object.

Answer (score 1):

`enum`s are a good solution if:

1. The number of items is fixed
2. All the information of the item is fixed as well (no loading of external files/resources/etc).

In a real application, you probably need to display the category on a display. This includes translating the category into the user's language which means there is an external dependency.

In such a case, you would use the `enum` as a key for a factory that gives you the text for each entry in the `enum`. The factory decouples your constant enum from the variables in the real world (like different/changing translations in the UI).